# Object variable or with variable not set for copying

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to be able to copy my data to the workbook.

I have built the code from here:

[Copying a range from all files within a folder and pasting into master workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405244/copying-a-range-from-all-files-within-a-folder-and-pasting-into-master-workbook)

which currently looks like this:

```
  Sub CopyData()
  Dim wbSource As Workbook
  Dim datTarget As Worksheet
  Dim datSource As Worksheet
  Dim strFilePath, strfile As String
  Dim strPath As String

  Set datTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Survey")
  strPath = GetPath

  If Not strPath = vbNullString Then

   strfile = Dir$(strPath & "*.xlsx", vbNormal)

   Do While Not strfile = vbNullString

  Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strfile)
  Set datSource = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1")

 Call Copy_Data(datSource, datTarget)

 wbSource.Close False
 strfile = Dir$()
  Loop
  End If
  End Sub

   Sub Copy_Data(ByRef datSource As Worksheet, datTarget As Worksheet)

  'QUESTION 1


  Const TM_PM As String = "*PM is required*"

  Dim que1 As Range
  Dim ans1 As Range
  Set que1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A100").Find(What:=TM_PM, _
                                     Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues)
                                     
  If Not que1 Is Nothing Then
  'MsgBox ("The question about PM or TM wasn't found")
  End If

  que1.Copy
  datTarget.Range("E1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
  End With

  Dim lrow1 As Long

  lrow1 = datTarget.Range("E" & datTarget.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1


   End Sub
```

I don't know why am I receiving errors:

**Object variable or with variable not set**

at the line:

```
     que1.Copy
```

I tried also something like this:

```
  With que1
  .Copy
  datTarget.Range("E1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
  End With
```

but the error was the same.

[Excel VBA Error: Object variable or With block variable not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68749841/excel-vba-error-object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set)

I know that the question is common, but I need to know what is wrong in this issue?

**UPDATE:**

[image]

In the "Locals" window I see, that variable is nothing. My situation is derivative from this query:

[Defining just part of the string as a constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70424853/defining-just-part-of-the-string-as-a-constant)

Have I done something wrong in the meantime?

Comment: That means nothing was found with `Set que1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A100").Find(What:=TM_PM, Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues)`. Use `If que1 Is Nothing Then MsgBox ("The question about PM or TM wasn't found") : Exit Sub : End If`

Comment: It doesn't work either

Comment: Yes, I have updated my query by adding the image

Comment: `que1.Copy` and the line that paste should be inside between `If Not que1 Is Nothing Then` and `End If`. This way it will only perform copy and paste if the `Find` method has a match i.e. `Not que1 is Nothing`

Comment: If Not que1 Is Nothing Then
MsgBox ("The question about PM or TM wasn't found")
Exit Sub
End If

Just this but the Message box there was quoted I don't need it frankly.

Comment: There doesn't seem much point in repeating the same question if you're not going to take on board the answers you get.

Comment: I am getting them and trying back and forth for nearly 2 hours mate

Comment: You didn't need to post this question, you could have continued with your previous one where Rory explained your problem.

Comment: You're getting an error because the text isn't found and that is most like because you're not searching in whatever is assigned to `datSource` but in "Sheet1" of the wordbook with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always best to test the result of a Find.

```vb
Sub Copy_Data(ByRef datSource As Worksheet, datTarget As Worksheet)
    
    'QUESTION 1
    Const TM_PM As String = "*PM is required*"
    
    Dim que1 As Range
    Set que1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A100").Find(What:=TM_PM, _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues)
                                         
    If que1 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The question about PM or TM wasn't found", vbExclamation
    Else
        que1.Copy
        datTarget.Range("E1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    End If

End Sub
```